# Cannot compare jquery.post result with string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

strange thing happens to me. I run post request via form and expect to get PHP data result with string `"Dobře"`, which seems to happen right as I can alert this string sucesfully. However, on next line I have if condition that should check if data variable (from callback) really contains this String Dobře. And this comparison never goes right. So I cannot get to line with `alert("gotcha")`. Any tips please?

```
 $.post("submit.php", {
        name1: name,
        email1: email,
        message1: message,
        contact1: contact,
        subject1: subject
    }, function(data) {
        $("#returnmessage").append(data); // Append returned message to message paragraph. NOT WORKIN FZUXK
        alert(data); // This writes "Dobře"
        if (data.length == 5 || data == "Dobře") {
            alert("gotcha");
            $("#form")[0].reset(); // To reset form fields on success.
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you using equal encodings (UTF-8, ISO,...) in your PHP script and your JS script?

Comment: do it with other string than "Dobře" ? could be a encoding problem...

Comment: Maybe its "Dobře " and not "Dobře". The extra space will fail data.length condition. Trim it and check for string length in console as well.

Comment: Did you tried `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your html head of your resulting page??

Comment: What charset (encoding) `submit.php` output in?

Comment: The OP is a type of ["ask-and-run" questioner](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256788/dealing-with-ask-and-run-questioners)

Comment: Thank guys, I have not thought about encoding issue at all. I will check when I will be home again. Sorry hindmost, I have not expected answers so quickly.